# can you explain pmap laziness and memory footprint?

Tags: clojure

The docs says about [pmap](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pmap):

> Like map, except f is applied in parallel. Semi-lazy in that the
>   parallel computation stays ahead of the consumption, but doesn't
>   realize the entire result unless required.

Can you kindly dis-obfuscate these two statements in some simple context?
Also is there for the `pmap` function, a `doseq` equivalent, having a memory footprint constant relative to the size of the iterated collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Semi-lazy in that the parallel computation stays ahead of the consumption

This means that `pmap` will do slightly more work than is strictly required by the sequence's consumer. This "working ahead" minimizes the wait for more items to be computed when the sequence is consumed. For example, if you're computing some infinite sequence in parallel and you only consume the first 50 results, `pmap` may have gone ahead and computed 50+N.

> but doesn't realize the entire result unless required.

This means it's only going to work ahead up to a certain threshold. The entire sequence won't be produced unless it's completely consumed (or almost completely consumed).

> Also is there for the `pmap` function, a `doseq` equivalent

You can use `doall` or `dorun` with `pmap` to produce side effects in parallel.

Here's an example of all three together, using an infinite sequence as input to `pmap`:

```
(def calls (atom 0))
(dorun (take 50 (pmap (fn [_] (swap! calls inc)) (range))))
;; @calls => 60
```

When this completes the value of `calls` will be over 50, even though we only consumed 50 items from the sequence.

Also read up on [reducers](https://clojure.org/reference/reducers) and core.async for another way to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't help but wonder why is it actually sensible, per the language designers, to "work ahead" in `pmap` but not in `map`?

Comment: Second comment being, it is my understanding that `pmap` will still realize the entire result collection, unlike `doseq` that will simply perform the expression on each item of the collection... even if wrapped with `doall`

Comment: Lazy sequences (like produced with `map`) are "chunked" in a conceptually similar way.

Comment: Thanks for the deliberation and the great example in context! I guess nothing shoehorned on top `pmap` would make it not hold to the head, making it a fit for composing a parallel version of `doseq`.

Comment: @matanster sounds like you are looking for the Claypoole library which offers parallel doseq and a "better" pmap https://github.com/TheClimateCorporation/claypoole

Comment: @matanster 1 year is not so long for a stable, working library. If it's not broken, it doesn't need fixed. Doesn't mean it's not getting used. Note that there are no open issues.

Comment: @johnbakers thanks, good to have good feedback on it before diving in

Answer (score 1):

While Taylor's answer is correct, I also gave a presentation on what happens inside of `pmap`, and how it's lazy, at Clojure West a few years ago. I know not everyone likes videos for learning, but if you do, it might be helpful: https://youtu.be/BzKjIk0vgzE?t=11m48s

(If you want non-lazy `pmap`, I second the endorsement for Claypoole.)